# How did dinosaurs end up on The Dinosaur Planet?

Tags: anne-mccaffrey, dinosaur-planet, ireta-series

I read a few of the books in Anne McCaffrey's "The Dinosaur Planet" series.  I can't recall -- was it ever explained how dinosaurs ended up on that planet?

Comment: I think @Aith deserves a nod for bringing this question to my attention

Comment: @Richard , You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thek <s>preserved</s> <s>kidnapped</s> rescued the dinosaurs. The planet is a combination petting-zoo & specialist eatery.

> "This planet's a zoo, Lunzie. A sanctuary for the dinosaurs. The Thek
>   have been stocking it for millennia — even before the cataclysm,"
>   Varian broke in excitedly. "Trizein, and all the other buffs were
>   right, the critters are from Mesozoic Terra."
>
> "Ger was caught in a massive earthquake," Kai said, "and buried so
>   deeply that it was unable to summon help. It had all but exhausted its
>   substance when the Thek started looking for it."
>
> "You see," Varian went on, "the Thek surveyed Old Terra eons ago and
>   were entranced by the dinosaurs. Long before the animals were
>   threatened with extinction by a climatic cataclysm, they had imported
>   them to Ireta which they knew would permanently provide the proper
>   environment. The Thek even brought the Rift grasses for the dinosaurs
>   since Ireta has no natural vitamin A. Dinosaurs are Thek pets." - <sub><sup>[Dinosaur Planet Survivors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345272463)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

Yes, near the end of the [second book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345272463), I believe.  During (or after?) the audience with the Tor, it comes out that they moved the dinosaurs offworld for 'preservation' purposes.